# Kafka Log Compaction

Tags: apache-kafka

When kafka does log compaction ,the log segments of a partition is split into "dirty"/"head" and "tail". I know the compaction happens only on the tail part of the segment.But does the dirty/head part include the active segment records along with the closed segment records which have earlier then log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms ?

Docs says

"If not set, all log segments are eligible for compaction except for the last segment, i.e. the one currently being written to. The active segment will not be compacted even if all of its messages are older than the minimum compaction time lag. "

But since head/dirty part of the segment does NOT get compacted anyway ,so does the active segment taken into consideration for head/dirt part of compaction?

Comment: This parameter refers to the message timestamp. Regardless of if the message is in the active segment or not the clock starts, but it can't be compacted until it isn't in the active segment. Once the active segment is rolled, the lag will be calculated from the message timestamp and the current time.

Comment: @dawsaw : So the head part includes the active segment?

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer to my question,my understanding initially was incorrect. The way it works is Certain head/dirty part of log also gets compacted and head does not include the active segments.
Below video at 40.0 From Jun Rao ,explains this :
https://vimeo.com/185844593/77f7d239a3?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWkRKall6azFZekJoTldGayIsInQiOiJvd2pTTmQ5WUIrUHUzelpDOVh5eStienVpZ1N1amlYMUc3Y3BMZWFTRjBMdEtaUXJRM2pLemNyTHB3bzkyYWVpSFRnMTN0NzdpV0VpMFp6d3V4YktMZ1dEaG1vNnBpMGR0OG9UbWUrUUZ6NDNpXC9GZmhGS1dVU1ZXcDJXdTRoSEMifQ%3D%3D